# ArrayList vs. Queue time complexity

Tags: java

If I am trying to remove the first element (index 0), would it be more time efficient to do list.remove(0) <- removes index 0 or use a queue and queue.dequeue(). I know delete for arraylist is o(n), does this still hold true if you provide the index to remove from? I am new to Java and algorithms, please bear with me if this is a dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ArrayList is only fast adding and removing close to the end.  It takes O(N) time to add or remove at or near the beginning even if you provide in index.

If you need a queue, use ArrayDeque.  It's fast at both ends.

Comment: What if the arraylist will hold a very few elements for example 3 or 4? It wouldn't matter right?

Comment: Then O(N) is small and it doesn't matter.  But ArrayDeque is also still fast in that case, so there's no reason to use ArrayList for the small cases.  If you need a queue, use a queue... that's what it's for :)

Answer (score 0):

> If I am trying to remove the first element (index 0), would it be more time efficient to do list.remove(0) <- removes index 0 or use a queue and queue.dequeue().

If you are removing always from beginning i.e. index 0 , then queue is better because it just needs to shift the head index and complexity is O(1) whereas for arraylist it involves left shifiting and complexity is O(n). Otherwise list is the choice if you want to remove random index.

> I know delete for arraylist is o(n), does this still hold true if you provide the index to remove from?

Yes. Because when you delete an element at particular index in an arraylist, it leaves a hole(or gap). This has to be filled because arrays are contiguous. So we have to left shift all elements that are towards the right of the removed element.